# Attempting to edit any post crashes iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, ios-app

After updating to 1.6.3.1 (through TestFlight), attempting to edit any post crashes the app. Seems to be any and all posts and restarting etc doesn't help. Any time you hit "edit", the app crashes.

---

- App Version: 1.6.3.1
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Comment: No repro on the same build and iOS version here, iPhone 6.  Any chance you can get a device log or crash log with the exception?

Comment: No repro. iPad Air2. App and iOS versions are same as yours.

Comment: No repro here either; same versions, iPhone 5c. You can find a crash log in Settings->Privacy->Diagnostics & Usage->Diagnostics & Usage Data->StackExchange-<date and time>.  Just select the whole thing, copy it, and add it to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been shipped to beta in 1.6.3.2.

There was a bug in migrating post drafts from CoreData to Realm, so this affects users who were have unsubmitted questions or answers when they update.

Comment: Thanks Brian, can confirm that's fixed.